# Exclude right margin on bootstrap container

Tags: python, css, twitter-bootstrap, plotly-dash, bootstrap-5

I'm using dash (python lib to make dashboards) and i'm having a problem with bootstrap components. I can´t exclude the right margin from the container. I'm usign this: `class_name='m-0'` on the container class. Already tried using `style={'margin': '0px'}` too, but keeps this same way.

```
# Layout
app.layout = dbc.Container(children=[
    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            html.Div(children=[
                html.H5(children='BAJA UEA'),
                html.H6(children="Visualização dos dados da telemetria"),
            ]),
        ]),
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Dropdown(['2400', '4800', '9600', '115200'], id='baudrate-dropdown', value='9600',
                         placeholder='Baudrate', style={'width': '150px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(portList, id='ports-dropdown', value='portList[0]', placeholder='COM Ports',
                         style={'width': '150px'}),
            dbc.Button('Connect', id='connect-button', style={'width': '150px'}),
        ], class_name='d-flex p-3 align-items-center justify-content-evenly'),
    ]),

    dbc.Row([
        dbc.Col([
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph_temperature',
                figure=graph_temperature
            ),
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph_velocidade',
                figure=graph_velocidade
            ),
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph_PRM',
                figure=graph_PRM
            ),
            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph_ACC',
                figure=graph_ACC
            )
        ]),
        dbc.Col([

        ])
    ])
], class_name='m-0')
```

[image]

Comment: You mean the vertical brown area on the right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is hard to diagnose as you have not provided a minimal example that we can run to demonstrate the behaviour.

From the snippet you have provided, the most likely explanation is that you are not using a fluid container, so your container will have a fixed width as set out in the [bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/containers/).

You can switch to a fluid container by setting `fluid=true` in your container definition ([docs here](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/layout/)), e.g.

```
app.layout = dbc.Container(
               fluid=True,
               children=[ ... ]
    )
```

Stylistically, I would also recommend using [Bootstrap Utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/) to manage margins, padding, flex, etc. rather than directly coding the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

`class_name='mx-0 w-100'`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/spacing/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/sizing/